# Can I declare file for output to console?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a routine to write (writeLines with sprintf) to output some values to the console.

I was asked to do the same output to a txt file.

What I have now is to duplicate the first set of "writeLine"s and change them to a write(..., file)

I am unable to find if I can declare a file to the console. What I am thinking is to have a function to do that and pass a parameter (file) and then just one set of statements for the write and call

```
diskfile <- file("results.txt", "w")
printresults("console")   # This is the part I don't know how
printresults(diskfile)
```

If I do the printresults to the file, I can read from it and present to the console. I am using:

```
cat(readlines, ...)
```

This works fine but I preferr to have the function solution.

Is there a way to  do that?

Thanks for your time,

EDIT>>> More specific

Can I do write(sprintf(...), CONSOLE)?

Comment: Maybe my question should be more clear:  Can I do write(sprintf(...), CONSOLE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would `sink()` (a favourite of mine) do the trick?

```
sink("file.txt", append = FALSE, split = TRUE)
print("Hello world")
sink()
```

With `split = TRUE` the output is passed to the console and the text file simulataneously, and the second call to `sink()` reverts output back to the console.

Both the console and `file.txt` print

> "Hello world"

Comment: Yes, this is what I want as well. Phil. Maybe my question is not clear: Can I do write(sprintf(...), CONSOLE)? I'll modify my question. I'll wait for a while, if you don't mind, to mark this as answer

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly. `sink()` changes where output is written to, so instead of answers being returned to the console they are written to the file. With the `split = TRUE` flag set, output will be written to both the console and file simultaneously. Is this what you're hoping for?

Comment: Yes, at the end it is.

Comment: Excellent, glad it's helped. I'll update my answer to clarify the `split` option